# AJAX running in a for loop - Callback function after for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, sharepoint

So I have a function that executes an ajax call in a for loop. I need to callback another function when the entire for loop is done. Since the ajax calls are running asynchronously, I'm not able to call the next function once the for loop is done.
 Here's my code:

```
for(let i=0; i< industryArray.length; i++){
        $.ajax({
            url: myurl + "_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('library')/items",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                RejectedSalesCount += data.d.results.length;
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        })
}

// Need to call myfunction() here
```

`myfunction()` is being called even before the ajax calls are executed. Thanks!

Comment: The fastest fix is keeping a tally of how many responses you got and then call the function when `industryArray.length` equals that number of returned responses. Personally I use promises instead of callbacks to avoid this kind of problems, so I can go `Promise.all( industryArray.map( fetch )).then( myfunction );`, but that's alot of work if your entire app uses $.ajax()

Comment: I have already tried it with Promises and for some strange reason the .then keeps executing and ends up in an infinite loop. I'll give it an other try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pendingRequests=0;
for(let i=0; i< industryArray.length; i++){
    if (condition) {
        pendingRequests++;
        $.ajax({
            url: myurl + "_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('library')/items",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                RejectedSalesCount += data.d.results.length;
                pendingRequests--;
                if(pendingRequests===0) {
                    otherFunction()
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
              doSomethingWithError(data)
            }
        })
     }
}
```

Comment: I actually have an if condition inside my for loop, so I can never be sure that each loop will execute the ajax. That is causing me all the issues.

Comment: You have to add the `succesCount += 1` to the error handler as well. Then no matter if the call succeeeded or not it'll still count as a response. Hence my comment before. This is the right idea with the wrong implementation. And @kratos, if you do not know in advance how many calls will be made, do not compare to industryArray.length, but to a second variable sendeCOunt or something.

Comment: I don't agree about error. Error should be handled differently and whole thing should usually fail if one fails.

Answer (score 0):

Set ajax asyc state false then it will work

this is a sample example to set ajax asyc false

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/submit/checkuser/",
    type : "get",
    async: false,
    success : function(userStatus) {
       if (userStatus == 'Disabled') { // check if user if disabled                    
       } else if (userStatus == 'Deleted') { // check if user if deleted
       } else {
       };
    },
    error: function() {
       connectionError();
    }
 });
```

Right now it wait for the function to get executed and moved to the next line

Comment: Setting ajax to sync is never a good idea. It gets your page stuck until all the ajax calls are executed.

Comment: @kratos ajax call inside for loop is also a very bad idea